# How to output a string in a variable removing the first character that is found using a substr function

Tags: php, substr

Hi I have a string named `$sql` which is:

`* FROM users WHERE users.id = '390'` (just and example, can be anything)

In my function I have a `$sql` variable which is the string above. I wish to get rid of the `*` before the `FROM`. My variable `$star` does output the `*`, but how do I code the `$sql` variable to exclude the `*` character in front of it?

```
$sql = $this->pdoquery($a, $v);
$star = substr($sql, 1, 2);
$query = "DELETE " . $sql;
```

I cannot alter the `$sql` variable to omit it in the `pdoquery` function, because I use it for `SELECT` etc.

Comment: `DELETE *` is not a valid (my)sql statement.

Comment: Exactly, that is why I wish to remove the *

Comment: where is the asterisk coming from? Do you not have control over it? If so, why include it?

Comment: Just remove it, that's all.

Comment: I cannot remove it, please read the whole question. I am using the `$sql` variable in other methods that use the `SELECT` etc

Comment: This sort of SQL statement manipulation is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and will almost certainly lead to problems. You probably want to look at building a new query from the data used to build the SELECT.

Comment: It is not a code smell, you have no idea of the rest of my code, I am just asking a simple question here.

Comment: that extra bit (you added in an edit) should have been part of the original post; how was I/we to know you couldn't manipulate it?

Comment: It is not an extra bit - it is very long. All I want is this small thing. The extra is not important. I just want to remove the first character of this string, that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove any leading character, you can use the php function [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php).

```
$sql = ltrim($sql, "*");

var_dump($sql); // Output: string(34) " FROM users WHERE users.id = '390'"
```

**Edit according to your update:**

Since you cannot modify the original variable, you can simply do it like this:

```
$without_star = ltrim($sql, "*");

var_dump($sql); // Output: string(35) "* FROM users WHERE users.id = '390'"
var_dump($without_star); // Output: string(34) " FROM users WHERE users.id = '390'"
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the output of `$without_star` still has the `*`

Comment: If thats the case, then your $sql variable does not contain the string you posted above. Have a look at this fiddle: http://codepad.org/zdMkSimM

Comment: Strange, when I `var_dump` the `$star` variable with `substr` it outputs the `*`. Is there a way to manipulate it with the `substr`?

Comment: `$sql` is definitely a string, so I don't understand why it is not working

Comment: Since your substr says substr($sql, 1, 2); it starts at the second character. It is zero based, so substr($sql, 0,1); would return the first character. Since 1, 2 returns * it actually returns "* ". Meaning you have a leading whitespace. You can then use ltrim($sql, " *");

Comment: @Horcrux it should be noted that `ltrim` is greedy and will remove the specified characters that prefixes the supplied string, until none are remaining. e.g. [`ltrim(' * * * *String', ' *')` results in `String`](https://3v4l.org/Pl3uD) I suggest using `preg_replace('/^\s?\*/', '', $string)` instead, to ensure the desired pattern is explicitly removed, rather than implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the asterisk '*'
you can replace in your code this line:

```
$star = substr($sql, 1, 2);
```

with:

```
$star = str_replace('*',"",$sql);
//this will remove all asterisk
```

If you only need to replace the first occurrence of '*' use:

```
$star = preg_replace('/\*/', '', $sql, 1);
```